Unable to read blob data from Azure
I have a method below to read blob file as per the fileName. The file exists in the Azure Blob Storage but still the code is throwing "The specified blob does not exists."
public async Task<string> ReadBlob(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_blobDataConnectionString)
                                                                .CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var cc = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_blobDataContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cc.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        return await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"ReadBlob: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

Below is the file I am trying to Read.


show us your blob structure

Please edit to show the complete error message, not a general summary. Also, show your container/blob content (the relevant part). What about other operations: can you list blobs in a container? Right now, it's difficult to know where you're having an issue. Please edit to provide a [mcve]

I was able to do upload operation in a container with same connection string.

I too agree with @David Makogon that it is a basic error, but my code works, when blob and container exists, it gives blob data . If not throws an exception saying either of one does not exist and below are my observations:
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

var rith_cs = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith54;AccountKey=vejgTwTStwCE1RQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
var rith_containerName="rithwik";
var rith_bn = "test11.txt";
CloudStorageAccount rith_sa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(rith_cs);
CloudBlobClient rith_bc = rith_sa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer rith_cn = rith_bc.GetContainerReference(rith_containerName);
if (!await rith_cn.ExistsAsync())
{
    throw new ApplicationException($"Hello Rithwik, Container {rith_containerName} does not exist.");
}
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = rith_cn.GetBlockBlobReference(rith_bn);
if (!await blockBlob.ExistsAsync())
{
    throw new ApplicationException($"Hello Rithwik, Blob {rith_bn} does not exist in container {rith_containerName}.");
}
var content = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);

My blob exists:

After Running the code:

Make sure you give all correct values(filename, container name and connection string). Make sure that the container is accessible. Filename should be given with extension too.

I have modified my Read method and now I am able to read the data from Blob
public async Task<string> ReadBlob(string fileName)
{
try
{
    var blobContainerClient = await _blobStorageClientFactory.CreateClient(_blobDataConnectionString, _blobDataContainerName);
   
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    var response =  blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync();

    using StreamReader reader = new(response.Result.Value.Content);
    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError(ex, $"ReadBlob: {ex.Message}");
    throw;
}}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
